# Schedule halt using ConsoleKit and Dbus

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, d-bus, consolekit

I have been playing with Dbus (versions 1.4.0, in Ubuntu 10.10 and 1.4.14) and ConsoleKit (versions 0.4.1 and 0.4.5) to reboot or halt my computer without being a superuser. Everything works fine in both versions.

If I execute the commands detailed in [this page](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=58094), the systems halts or reboots without troubles. Now, what I'd like to know is whether I can schedule that halt/reboot at a certain time (still using Dbus/ConsoleKit). Something like the `shutdown` command can do (`shutdown -h 10:56`) Is that possible?

I can always use an `at` or `cron`, but if I can do it straight with `dbus`, that'd be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `halt`, `shutdown` or `reboot` from the `cron` is cleaner solution, because `d-bus` is just messaging system, and cron already calls as a root. But if you need to tell about the shutdown to another applications thru d-bus, try calling this:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```